# How do I convert ISO8601 to utc using joda time in JAVA?

Tags: java, jodatime, timezone-offset

I would like to convert:

```
2014-08-12T05:43:00-05:00 (YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:MM:SS-OFFSET)
```

To:

```
20140812104300Z (YYYYMMDDHHMMSSZ)
```

Comment: Your timestamp doesn't make sense. It's either Z (which is UTC) or -0500, but not both. Or is the Z a literal Z in your timestamp, which doesn't express Zulu time?

Comment: I believe its a Zulu time

Comment: Then the offset doesn't make sense (if you have a UTC timestamp, you don't have an offset). Also, can you show what you have already tried?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just edited my post. I am working on test automation (using TestNG) and I need to validate above dates. In my example, the "20140812104300Z-0500" OFFSET is important because time is getting converted according to Offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;

public class mydate {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        java.util.Date date = new DateTime("2014-08-12T05:43:00-05:00").toDate();
        DateTime dateTimeUtc = new DateTime( date, DateTimeZone.UTC ); // Joda-Time can convert from java.util.Date type which has no time zone.
        String output = dateTimeUtc.toString().replace("-", "").replace("T", "").replace(":", "").substring(0,14)+"Z"; // Defaults to ISO 8601 format.
        System.out.println(output);

    }

}
```

Input: 2014-08-12T05:43:00-05:00

Output: 20140812104300Z